# Not able to send mail using Java Mail Api

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send mail to user using google .My code was working fine on localhost , I tried deploying it on server , there it was causing issue of Authentication , but now its not working on my localhost as well, Here is the error I am getting :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 sz6sm1026673pab.5 - gsmtp
```

I thought might be issue with the gmail account i am using to send mail, I tried with another account still the same issue .

Can anybody have a idea what causing this issue , is it my ip address is blocked or something as I tried repeadly.

Below is the configuration in my xml :

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <property name="port" value="587" />
        <property name="username" value="dummy1@gmail.com" />
        <property name="password" value="abc1234" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <!-- Use SMTP transport protocol -->
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <!-- Use SMTP-AUTH to authenticate to SMTP server -->
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <!-- Use TLS to encrypt communication with SMTP server -->
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: @Deckard27 I did added my xml configuration but as I said it was working fine before I tried several failing attempts on live server , and now it stops on local

Comment: @Deckard27 I can login in gmail

Comment: Does your actual password contain any special characters?

Comment: @BillShannon No it doesn't initially it was just the alphabets than I change it to alphabets + numbers combination. Also last night I tried without xml configuration all the properties and credentials in a Mail util class and it works why it has the problem with spring I dont understand which was working fine few days back

Answer (score 0):

The authentication error might be misleading, as it could be a configuration error. Can you post the code that you are using to do try to send the Mail?

Comment: check above I added the xml configuration using for account

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like gmail is rejecting your login.  Did you try to login to gmail with your credentials that you use in the code on the web?  Perhaps there is a fault in your deployment which does not properly communicate the credentials to gmail.  If you do that a few times, gmail will time restrict your login attemps as a safety precaution for brute force attacks.

Check if you can login to your account on the web first.

Comment: on web it works fine , i tried testing with another account it has same issue .

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I had as well. The solution was to change the GMail settings to allow less secure applications access to your gmail account. [Go here to change the settings](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps), and then run your application again.